# ERD - issue about entities

Tags: erd

Im making an ERD now for medicine care.
I have an issue with 2 entities:
Patient and caregiver.
The caregiver is a person that helps for the patient and can do features on the application for the patient.

For now I choose that the patient is a separate user from the caregiver.
If its like that,I need to do a seperate entities for the caregiver and for the patient. When I do this , there is an overload on the ERD because the 2 entities can do the same thing on the system so they have the same connections to other entities.
In addition , they have just one attribute that is different between them and this is the diagnosis of the patient.

What to do?

Comment: Your description isn't clear - in particular, the phrase "the caregiver is a separate user from the caregiver". Anyway, it sounds like you're asking about modeling subtypes/supertypes on an ERD. This is a common topic, try searching StackOverflow with those terms.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into adding the caregiver as a sub class if all the rows are the same apart from one. But having them both as separate entities wouldnt be an overload on the database as long as you add primary/foreign keys correctly. Have you got a current ERD i can look at?